# How to check if computer name is already exist in the domain My script used in each pc

Tags: powershell

My script used in each pc in our network to rename pc but i want to check domain is the new name is already exist
Any help please

```
$Searcher = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$searcher = [adsisearcher]"(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer)(name=$global:NewComputerName))"
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(('name'))
$searchResult = $searcher.FindAll()
if($searchResult.count -eq 1)
 {
  $Result = $true
 }
  else
{
  $Result = $False
}
```

So then i use this to check if the result is true or false

```
elseif ($Result -match 'true')
{
    $msgBoxInput7 = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('computer is exist', 'OK')

     switch  ($msgBoxInput7) {

    'OK' {
                $groupbox1.ResumeLayout()
                $form1.ResumeLayout()
                $form1.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
         }
     }
}
```

Please help me this code doesn’t work

Comment: don't use `true` for your test - instead, use `$True`. the 1st is just a string ... the 2nd is a boolean.

Comment: thanks for your replay yes i use it like this $Result -eq $True but still not working

Comment: any other way to achieve my goal

Comment: please, edit your posted code to show what you are really using.

Comment: what is the rest of your code? the 2nd part starts with an `elseif` ... and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: As aside, Why use `.FindAll()` and not `.FindOne()`. Also, why not use module ActiveDirectory and do something like `if (Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq 'TheComputerNameYouAreSearching'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { 'exists' }` ??

Comment: Ok the first if is to check if the new name is equal the computer itself and whan i use  Get-ADComputer I get error (is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet) so this script used in user machines so it not server or admin machin

Comment: @iappnet - ok ... but where is the rest of the 2nd batch of code? what you posted WILL NOT RUN ... and you are supposed to post a _minimal, working code example_.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Get-ADComputer (as Theo said in the comment):

```
if(get-adcomputer -filter "Name -eq 'nameToFind'"){
   "Exists"
   }else{
   "Not exists"
   }
```

If you will receive error like:

```
The term 'Get-ADComputer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function etc..
```

You need to import the module before this command using `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`

You may even receive another issue:

```
Get-ADComputer : Unable to find a default server with Active Directory Web Services running
```

If so, please add parameter -Server with AD server name, example:

```
if(get-adcomputer -Server "DC" -filter "Name -eq 'nameToFind'"){
   "Exists"
   }else{
   "Not exists"
```

}